# Youtube Comments on Firefox with Noscript and ABP

Tags: firefox, youtube, adblock, comments, noscript

All videos display a "Comments currently unavailable" message with the comments frame  collapsed. Temporarily allowing Noscript on the entire page doesn't fix it. Disabling ABP on the entire page doesn't fix it. I'm sure millions of users use the same combination of add-ons on Firefox, so how do you guys enable the youtube comments section?

Comment: What other extensions do you have?  You are correct I am able to display the YouTube comments with both of those extensions installed

Comment: A bunch of other add-ons, but none that affect content the way ABP and noscript do. Just stuff like Tab Scope, HTTPS-Everywhere, etc. Do you allow specific scripts to run on youtube? Is ABP disabled on youtube?

Comment: Disabling all extensions didn't fix the problem, so I reset Firefox to defaults, reimported my extensions and addons and fired Firefox back up. Allowing the necessary scripts on youtube now enables the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Allow cookies on `www.youtube.com`. Disabling cookies will show an error message instead of loading comments.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Adblock preferences interface. Select 'Custom Filters' tab. Click the 'Add filter' button. Paste the below into the line that appears:

```
@@||apis.google.com/*/render/comments?*www.youtube.com*
```

Reload any YouTube page that is currently open. Comments should now show up on YouTube videos.